# Android Volley doesn't seem to be able to connect to Flask localhost address for GET method for return String from Flask?

Tags: android, python, flask, android-volley

**This is the Android Volley code :**

```
// I already add the uses-permission for INTERNET to manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

// and add volley to gradle depedencies
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'


StringRequest stringRequest; 
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;  

String url = "http://localhost:5000/bacon"; // This is the localhost to FLask

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(BaconActivity.this);
stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(BaconActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    redirectLinkToLogin();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(BaconActivity.this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**This is the Flask code :**

```
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/bacon', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bacon():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return 'You are probably using GET'
    else:
        return 'You are probably using POST'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost')
```

When I run the app, my Volley didn't connect to my Flask (I already run the Flask before running the app). So instead of retrieving the return String, the code runs to the Response.ErrorListener everytime.

I'm trying to get the return String from Flask to the localhost, and Toast the return String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> String url = "http://localhost:5000/bacon"; // This is the localhost to FLask
> ```

Actually, no. That's the localhost to the running device. Whether that is the emulator, or your physical Android device.

You may also need Flask to run on `host='0.0.0.0'`

You need to use the actual IP of your computer running Flask. Android emulator uses `10.0.2.2`, I believe

Comment: Host with '0.0.0.0' didn't work. Site can't be reached. Could you please explain further the second part?

Comment: My computer IP from my router you mean?

Comment: Alright. I fix it. Thanks, you are right about using my computer IP. I change the host to my computer IP.

Comment: As an extra info, if other people reading and don't know your computer IP is. In windows, open your network connections, choose which connection your computer uses, click Ethernet, and click Details. You should find your computer IP. Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Or open CMD and run 'ipconfig'.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on my Mac by going to System Preferences > Network and noting my ip.

Then I restarted my dev appserver with this ip address.

`dev_appserver.py --host="192.168.1.109" app.yaml`

And I used this same ip address in my `JsonObjectRequest` declaration as well (as part of making a [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) Request.

Now I can use Volley to make GET calls to my local Google Endpoints.

Comment: This worked for me with Android Studio, Mac, and MAMP.